# getting part of dictionary by value in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key, key-value

I have dictionary:

```
teamDictionary = {
1: {'name': 'Bob', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
3: {'name': 'Sam', 'team': 'B', 'status': 'Travel'},
4: {'name': 'Phil', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
}
```

I need to get all smaller dictionary where team is C. My cod is:

```
team_leave = [teamDictionary[a] for a, b in teamDictionary.items() if b['team'] == 'C' ]

print(team_leave)

[{'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}, {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}]
```

But I need to get

```
{
    2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
    5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
    }
```

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension instead:

```
{k: d for k, d in teamDictionary.items() if d['team'] == 'C'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[Dictionary Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)**:

```py
team_leave = {key: item for key, item in teamDictionary.items() if item['team'] == 'C'}

print(team_leave)
```

Ouput:

```py
{2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}, 5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 print({key: values for key, values in teamDictionary.items() if values['team'] == 'C'}
```